# Prevent Chromium/Chrome from displaying URLs under certain directories

Tags: networking, chrome, web

I'd prefer a low-level approach, e.g. changing the hosts file would be perfect (but AFAIK only domains, not directories can be rerouted there). I'm looking for a way to block ads without resorting to AdBlock or a similar app-based solution. Is there a way?

Comment: Have you considered Hardware Level DNS redirection like [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/)??  The account panel has a user configurable blacklist.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'm looking into it. But I'd prefer (and am still hoping for) a native, i.e. Linux- or Chrom*-based solution

Comment: OpenDNS is hardware level, ie. works by updating options in your Routers etc.  The only software you need to configure it is a web browser.  The only time you need to add software is when you're using a Bridged Setup.  If you don't know what a Bridged Setup is, you probably don't need to worry. See [Linux IP Updater for Dynamic Networks](https://support.opendns.com/entries/23554765-Linux-IP-Updater-for-Dynamic-Networks).  `ddclient` has always been native.

Comment: The OpenDNS blacklist allows to block domains with implied wildcards -- e.g. listing `domain.com` would block `*.domain.com` but how to block a directory without blocking its domain?

Comment: The blacklist can do global blocking as you suggested, or per page blocking if you list the entire link. Listing link by link implies a specific block, while allowing parts of the global domain through.  Implied Blocking is done with wild cards where as Explicit Blocking is done with exact linking.

Comment: Implicit Blocking - `*.doman.com` vs Explicit Blocking `http://www.domain.com/directory/page.html`.  Explicit Blocking is the entire link.

Comment: Can I use a wildcard (an implied or explicit one) to block e.g. `domain.com/dir*`? If I understood correctly, blocking `domain.com/dir` as an exact link (if possible in the first place) would still let `domain.com/dir/foo` through. Blocking the entire contents of a directory with exact links is unfeasible

Comment: I believe that will work...

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to be the case. Wildcards are only for URL prefixes. Also, OpenDNS Basic supports blocking of up to 25 individual domains only, and blocking advertising providers as a category is not an option. https://support.opendns.com/entries/26514730-Web-Content-Filtering-and-Security
https://support.opendns.com/entries/26022379-Can-I-Block-Advertisers-and-Ad-Servers-